# How to share static field across various workers(JVM) in storm?

Tags: static, jvm, apache-storm, worker

I have a static field(counter) in one of my bolt. Now if i run the topology in cluster with various worker. Each JVM is going to have its own copy of static field. But I want a field which can be shared across by workers. How can i accomplish that?

I know i can persist the counter somewhere and read that in each JVM and update it(synchronously). But that will be performance issue. Is there any way out through Storm?

Comment: Storm does not offer any support for shared state over multiple workers. You need to build your own custom solution, ie, use some external system/mechanism to share the counter. Btw: if you want to have a consistent state, updating the counter in a synchronized way is mandatory... You have to pay the performance penalty for it.

Answer (score 1):

The default Storm api only provides at-least-once processing guarantee.  This might or might not be what you want depending on whether the accuracy of the counter matters (e.g. when a tuple is reprocessed due to a worker failure, counter is incremented incorrectly)

I think you can look into Trident, which is a high-level API for Storm that can provide exactly-once processing guarantee and the abstractions (e.g. Trident State) for persisting states using databases or in-memory stores.  Cassandra has a column type for counters which might be suitable for your use case.

**Persisting trident state in memcached**
https://github.com/nathanmarz/trident-memcached

**Persisting trident state in Cassandra**
https://github.com/Frostman/trident-cassandra